# Should "request" cookies have the secure flag set?

Tags: django, security, cookies

I have a django app. That app has 2 main cookies that are returned from the server (csrftoken and sessionid). I set the SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE and CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE flags in my settings.py file to True, and if I examine the initial request to login to my app I see that both of those cookies have the "secure" flag set in the response from the server.

When I am examining cookies in my app, I notice there are "request cookies" and "response cookies". The "response cookies" are the ones that have their flags set. The request cookies do not.

My question: Is there some way to force "request cookies" to have their secure flag set? Is this even a security concern? My application traffic is over https, so all connections between the browser and the server will already be encrypted from that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't really work that way ... The flags are only present in the `Set-Cookie` header (the response).

When the client (a browser) receives a `Set-Cookie` header, it will store the flags together with the cookie value, but *only for its own usage* (so that the browser itself can know when and where to send the cookie value if necessary).

The `Cookie` header (request) cannot contain flags; it is only a list of `<cookie-name>=<cookie-value>` pairs and when you (the server) receive them, you're not even guaranteed to have set them yourself.
That's because *any* application under the same domain name can set cookies for that said domain. For example, an application running on *example.com/foo* would be able to set a cookie for *example.com/bar*, or even for *another.example.com*.

However, excluding the possibility of really horrible browser bugs, you can be sure that if you set the "secure" flag for a cookie in your response, the receiving browser won't send it over a non-encrypted connection.
It's not really 100% guaranteed, but it's really the only option you have and the pretty much the whole web relies on browsers behaving properly, so you're not alone in that.

Sadly, that's just how cookies work. Read the official standard for them [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) if you're interested in learning more about them.